# Añadir Keys y Values a IDictionary - C#

Tags: c#, mvc

¿Cómo puedo agregar valores a un IDictionary? Actualmente tengo una clase donde hay solo una propiedad de tipo `IDictionary<string, int>`y necesito *setearla* con unos valores que vienen del controlador.

**Controller**:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(TestViewModel value)
{
     //Código
}
```

La clase `TestViewModel` es la que posee la propiedad `IDictionary`

**Clase TestViewModel**:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
   public IDictionary<string, int> Ids { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ¿Quieres "setearlas" en tu Controlador o como valores por defecto de tu clase TestViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para *setear* valores al diccionario debes crear una variable de tipo `Dictionary`, en lugar de la interfaz `IDictionary`:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> Ids { get; set; }
```

Para agregar valores al diccionario utiliza el método `Add` que en su primer parámetro reciba la llave y en el segundo el valor:

```
Ids.Add("Llave1", 1);
Ids.Add("Llave2", 2);
Ids.Add("Llave3", 3);
```

Recuerda que las llaves deben ser valores únicos, si se llegara a agregar una llave existente te enviará un error.

Answer (score 0):

La interface proporciona la definición de los métodos necesarios para gestionar un diccionario. Para poderla utilizar necesitas alguna implementación de IDictionary. En tu caso, tienes la implementación Dictionary.

Ejemplo:

```
IDictionary<string, int> Ids = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Ids.Add("Key1", 1);
Ids.Add("Key2", 2);
Ids.Add("Key3", 3);
```